# WordPress Rest API response

Tags: rest-api

Is it possible to return plain text in a WordPress Rest API response?
By default this seems to return JSON.
Any advice on the recommended way to override this? 
Doing a json_decode() on my response object before it is returned from the callback function does not have any effect, so I assume the JSON gets created after this.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of text format? Can you give an example and show what you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to subscribe to a webhook and am being sent a challenge key in the query string, When I return the response string it has quotation marks around it (because it has been converted to json). I need to return the string value only, without any quotation marks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to output your headers with the response. Then just kill the request with `exit();`.

The default is usually to return a value and let the process encode and output for you.

---

Based on http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print_r( array('foo'=>'bar'));
    exit();
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/test/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```